# Modificar código para evitar um XMLHttpRequest com $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, getjson

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação aqui, e uso um objeto JSON para popular, porém quando uso o `$.getJSON()` o Chrome dá o seguinte erro:

***XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/JeanCarlos/Documents/GitHub/NetworkDiagram/Application/Object.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.***

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
// This function get error XMLHtmlRequest, because this not supported protocol LOCAL.
$.getJSON('Object.json', function(data) {       
    console.log('success');
    var table = '';
    $.each(data.activies, function(key, val) {
        table += '<table>';
        table += '<tbody>';
        table += '<tr><td>' + val.EarlyStart + '</td><td>' + val.Duration + '</td><td>' + val.EarlyFinish + '</td></tr>';
        table += '<tr><td colspan="3">' + val.ActivityName + '</td></tr>';
        table += '<tr><td>' + val.LateStart + '</td><td>' + val.TotalFloat + '</td><td>' + val.LateFinish + '</td></tr>';
        table += '</tbody>';
        table += '</table>';
    });     
    $("#content").append(table);
}).error(function() {
    console.log('error');
});
});
```

Objeto.JSON

```
{"activies" = [{
"EarlyStart": "1",
"Duration": "10",
"EarlyFinish": "2",     
"ActivityName": "Activity 1",
"LateStart": "4",
"TotalFloat": "4",
"LateFinish": "5"                      
}]}
```

Entendo o problema, que esse erro é um " meio segurança" que o chrome usa, porém preciso modificar esse código para não dar mais esse problema.

Comment: Você não pode carregar nada do sistema de arquivos e não tem como contornar, em nenhum browser. Para que funcione, use um servidor web, tem diversas alternativas na web, em Node, Python ou usando o WebMatrix. Daí você estará carregando do próprio servidor e não terá esse problema.

Answer (score 0):

Como disse o Sergio Garcia no comentário, isso não é possível no Chrome, porém você pode criar um servidor http pelo Node.js v5+ facilmente

Servidor: `server.js`

```
// Inicie o servidor na porta 8000 e mantenha o socket
// aberto até que o processo seja finalizado.
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  // O conteúdo da resposta deve ser interpretado como texto
  // HTML com codificação UTF-8
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');

  try {
    // Leia o arquivo index.html e retorne o conteúdo HTML
    // para o cliente.
    res.writeHeader(200);
    res.write(fs.readFileSync('./index.html').toString());

  } catch(e) {
    // Houve um erro ao tentar ler o arquivo.
    res.writeHeader(500);
    res.write(JSON.stringify(e,0,2));

  }

  // Enviar o buffer ao cliente.
  res.end();
}).listen(8000).timeout = 0;
```

Cliente: `index.html`

```
// Arquivo index.html
<script>
  // Código da sua requisição
</script>
```

Os arquivos `server.js` e `index.html` devem estar na mesma pasta.